# Print multidimensional array and style it

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, nested

I've an array built this way

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent_id] => 
            [text] => Top level comment
            [level] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 
            [text] => Top level comment
            [level] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [text] => Response to #1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [text] => Response to #1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                            [text] => Response to #3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [text] => Response to #2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [11] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 11
                                            [parent_id] => 10
                                            [text] => Response to #10
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [13] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 13
                                                            [parent_id] => 11
                                                            [text] => Response to #11
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [14] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 14
                                                                            [parent_id] => 13
                                                                            [text] => Response to #13
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [12] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 12
                                            [parent_id] => 10
                                            [text] => Response to #10
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 
            [text] => Top level comment
            [level] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent_id] => 
            [text] => Top level comment
            [level] => 1
        )

)
```

JSON

```
{"6":{"id":6,"parent_id":null,"text":"Top level comment","level":1},"1":{"id":1,"parent_id":null,"text":"Top level comment","level":1,"children":{"2":{"id":2,"parent_id":1,"text":"Response to #1"},"3":{"id":3,"parent_id":1,"text":"Response to #1","children":{"4":{"id":4,"parent_id":3,"text":"Response to #3"}}},"10":{"id":10,"parent_id":1,"text":"Response to #2","children":{"11":{"id":11,"parent_id":10,"text":"Response to #10","children":{"13":{"id":13,"parent_id":11,"text":"Response to #11","children":{"14":{"id":14,"parent_id":13,"text":"Response to #13"}}}}},"12":{"id":12,"parent_id":10,"text":"Response to #10"}}}}},"5":{"id":5,"parent_id":null,"text":"Top level comment","level":1},"9":{"id":9,"parent_id":null,"text":"Top level comment","level":1}}
```

What's the easiest way to echo it out and style it? Say like reddit. I'd like to do the styling in the view file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#ol_and_ul, but I would rather go with custom function that is looping through array and generating HTML.

EDIT:

```
function draw_comments($comments, $level = 0)
{
    echo  '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
    foreach($comments as $comment)
    {
        draw_comment($comment);

        if(!empty($comment['children']))
            draw_comments($comment['children'], $level+1);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

function draw_comment($comment)
{
    echo '<li>';
    echo $comment['text'];
    echo '</li>';
}

draw_comments($comments_array);
```

Comment: Whould you like to share how you'd loop through that array? I don't know how to do what because number of children = x.